# How we can draw live shadow on rotationEffect for Angle(degrees: 0) in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

This is very strange bug or issue for me! I have a red Rectangle() which rotate with user single tap, and after that I have a shadow view for my Rectangle(). after rotation there is more than 1 shadow view for Rectangle(), which is get rendered over each other and not working! It is not logical for me, why it is happening? the .shadow must return just 1 view but in this case returns more than 1 view for Angle(degrees: 0) if you start with more than 0 everything working just fine for example use this: Angle(degrees: 10). As soon as you start the app with Angle(degrees: 0) it would not work!

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var rotationAngle: Angle = Angle(degrees: 0) //← Here

var body: some View {
    
    
    

    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.red)
        .frame(width: 200, height: 100, alignment: .center)
        .rotationEffect(rotationAngle)
        .onTapGesture
        {
            rotationAngle += Angle(degrees: 10)
        }
        .shadow(color: Color.black, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 20)
        
        
    
    
    
        
        
    }
}
```

This is my salvation for temporary usage:

```
.rotationEffect(rotationAngle == Angle(degrees: 0) ? Angle(degrees: 0.001) : rotationAngle)
```

what is yours?

Comment: That's a weird bug.  Workaround: start with `Angle(degrees: 360)`.

Comment: yes! that is strange! If I gave Angle(degrees: 0.00000000001) it would work fine, but it would not work for 0 or 0.0

Comment: If you start at `Angle(degrees: -20)`, it works fine until it hits `10`.

Comment: yes, if i use -20.0000000001 would work fine! but not -20

Comment: I think this is a swiftUI bug related to shadow func from apple, forgot to clear old contextView, it does not mater how much is your rotation Angle step or from which degree you are starting! it does problem to clear context for degree zero! EVEN with radians! If you start with zeo it would not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue has been soled with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1 that was a bug of older version.